# Python 3: read file with 'rb' mode as Python 2 did

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, types, encoding

I am working with some midi files and [an older Python 2 library that transforms midi files to wav files](https://github.com/chrisdonahue/nesmdb/issues/5). Back in the day, Python 2 read files using `rb` mode as raw strings that contained byte information, e.g.:

```
'MThd\x00\x00\x00'
```

Python 3, by contrast, reads that data as bytes:

```
b'MThd\x00\x00\x00'
```

For reference, a full sample midi file read by Python3 prints like this:

```
b'MThd\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x01\x00\x05V"MTrk\x00\x00\x00\x1d\x00\xffQ\x03\x07\xa1 \x00\xffX\x04\x04\x02\x18\x08\x82\x93P\xffX\x04\x01\x00\x18\x08\x01\xff/\x00MTrk\x00\x00\x00-\x00\xff\x03\x02p1\x00\xc0\x00\x00\x90<\x0f\xa2:<\x00\xa2:>\x0f\xa2:>\x00\xa2:@\x0f\xa2:@\x00\xa2:A\x0f\xa2:A\x00\x01\xff/\x00MTrk\x00\x00\x00-\x00\xff\x03\x02p2\x00\xc1\x00\x00\x91@\x0f\xa2:@\x00\xa2:A\x0f\xa2:A\x00\xa2:C\x0f\xa2:C\x00\xa2:E\x0f\xa2:E\x00\x01\xff/\x00MTrk\x00\x00\x00\x1d\x00\xff\x03\x02tr\x00\xc2\x00\x00\x920\x0f\xa2:0\x00\xe7.$\x0f\xa2:$\x00\x01\xff/\x00MTrk\x00\x00\x00M\x00\xff\x03\x02no\x00\xc3\x00\x00\x93\x08\x04\x88N\x08\x00\x99l\t\x04\x88N\t\x00\x99l\n\x04\x88N\n\x00\x99l\x0b\x04\x88N\x0b\x00\x99l\x0c\x04\x88N\x0c\x00\x99l\r\x04\x88N\r\x00\x99l\x0e\x04\x88N\x0e\x00\x99l\x0f\x04\x88N\x0f\x00\x01\xff/\x00'
```

Is there a way to make Python 3's 'rb' read option return the same data returned by Python 2's 'rb' read option? Any help on this question would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is the same data. Python 2 `str` is a byte string, which is `bytes` in Python 3. Which concrete problem are you encountering as a result of this? (If it’s just about how it’s logged, you can remove the `b` with `repr(byte_string)[1:]`.)

Comment: Thanks for your note! My trouble is in slicing the objects. Taking a slice of the Python 3 b'' object returns an integer, while taking a slice of the Python 2 object returns a byte. Is there a nice solution to this quandry?

Comment: Aha! A one character long slice from a byte object returns a byte in Python 3! e.g. `b'GIF89a'[2:3]` http://python3porting.com/problems.html